# How can I interpret the features obtained from Chem.RDKFingerprint(mol)

Tags: rdkit

I have done the following to obtain the fingerprint from mol file. By converting fp.ToBitString() gives me a vector of length 2048. When I count the 1's are the same as the number of atoms in a molecule. How can we interpret this vector? Any suggestions of link for the explanation would be great.

```
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(ms)
fp = Chem.RDKFingerprint(mol)
fp.ToBitString()
```

Here is the vector I obtained

```
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather the `RDKFingerprint` is a "Daylight-like" substructure fingerprint that uses a bit vector where each bit is set by the presence of a particular substructure within a molecule. The default settings (`maxPath` default=7) consider substructures that are a maximum of 7 bonds long. As there is no predefined substructure set, it is impossible to set a bit for each existing pattern so each key is considered as a seed to a pseudo-random number generator ('hashing'). The output of this is a set of bits (`nBitsPerHash`, default=2) with numbers between 0 and `fpSize` default=2048 which is used to set the corresponding bits in the fingerprint.

RDKit has a nice utility for interpreting the bits set:

```
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit import Chem

smiles = 'OC(CN1C=NC=N1)(CN1C=NC=N1)C1=C(F)C=C(F)C=C1'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)

bit_info = {}
fp = Chem.RDKFingerprint(mol, maxPath=5, bitInfo=bit_info)
print(list(fp.GetOnBits())[:10])  # print the first 10 bits set to 1

# using the bit_info dictionary populated by RDKit prepare a visualisation
Draw.DrawRDKitBit(mol, 60, bit_info)

# draw multiple bits (12)
tpls = [(mol, x, bit_info) for x in bit_info]
Draw.DrawRDKitBits(tpls[:12], molsPerRow=4, legends=[str(x) for x in bit_info][:12])
```

Some recommended reading:

- [RDKit Documentation](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.html#rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.RDKFingerprint)
- [Daylight Fingerprint Theory](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.finger.html)
- [RDKit UGM Fingerprint Slides](https://www.rdkit.org/UGM/2012/Landrum_RDKit_UGM.Fingerprints.Final.pptx.pdf)
- [RDKit Blogspot (Bit Drawing)](http://rdkit.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-new-fingerprint-bit-rendering-code.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and recommended readings.